# Android Studio Gradle: how to get variant/flavour in custom assets processor task

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors

I have simple assets processing gradle task prepare_assets in Android Studio 3.1.3. It is linked to preBuild task:

```
preBuild.dependsOn(prepare_assets)
```

Now I have several flavors for different resolution versions and I want to let prepare_assets know what assets to process. Maybe I don't get the idea of Gradle, but I can't understand how to achieve this: I tried to set variable in config phase

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        buildType = variant.buildType.name // sets the current build type
    }
```

but when I read variable in my task it always the same.

Answer (score 0):

In flavours section declaration:

```
all { flavor ->
    task("${flavor.name.capitalize()}_prepare_assets") {
        println "*** conf TEST for ${flavor.name.capitalize()}***"

        doLast {
            println "*** action TEST ${flavor.name.capitalize()}***"
            if (flavor.name.equals("fullhd"))
            {
              //WARNING: to call copy, javaexec closures here use project.copy and project.javaexec!
            }
            else
            {
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the bottom of file adding dependenses for runtime created android tasks for all flavors:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
        if (theTask.class.name.contains("AppPreBuildTask_Decorated"))
        {
            for (Iterator iterator = android.productFlavors.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String flv_name =  iterator.next().name.capitalize();
                if (theTask.name.contains(flv_name+"Debug") || theTask.name.contains(flv_name+"Release"))
                    theTask.dependsOn "${flv_name}_prepare_assets";
            }
    }
}
```